# wrapping non-text elements around a float

Tags: html, css

I have a liquid layout that has worked for me for some time.  I float `<div>`s either right or left.  A div will typically have an image and a caption in it.

Text items wrap properly around floats.  However certain items do not:  `<table>` `<hr>` will do one of two things: Either they intrude onto the floated div, or they skip down below floated div.

Is there a way using just css so that items like `<hr>` will size to the currently available width, as text entities do?  That is if the text is currently wrapping around a 40% width float, and there is an `<hr>` with width of 80%, then that `<hr>` will do 80% of the 60% remaining, and put a 48% width hr in the wrapping text.

Comment: Create a simplified example and post it here, make sure to include your desired behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, when you use a percentage in the [`width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property) property,

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the
>   generated box's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#containing-block).

If you want to calculate the percentage with respect to the available space left by floating elements, you must wrap you element inside a containing block that occupies the remaining space.

```css
#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden; /* Clear float */
}
#float {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  background: #f99;
}
#block { /* Containing block that fills remaing space */
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #99f;
}
hr {
  width: 80%; /* With respect to available space */
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="float">Float</div>
  <div id="block">
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting.  If I don't style the hr at all, it behaves the way I want.  The uses the available space and wraps properly.  It scales to 100% of the presently availabe space.

Comment: If I put a width = % that is smaller than the available space  e.g. 40%, then it is centered in the available space, but uses 40% of the current container for it's width.

Comment: You are correct.  If I wrap the hr as follows:  <div markdown="1" style="width:60%">
***
</div>  it works.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford You can format code using `\``. See [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: A COMMENT, not in the code box.  I can't even make 2 paragraphs in a comment, let alone put a code snippet in.